# How to show plotted data with big value differences?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the data `car_crashes` that I am plotting using `ggplot`. It has 3 different data sets as seen below 
[image]

but since Average of Cars is huge, the other values do not show even bit because they are in the range of 100. If I remove the average of cars data, the plot actually looks like this 
[image]

Is there a way I can show all the data in one plot so that at least I can see the num of crashes plot? 
The code I used is below:

```
carcrashes_figure <- ggplot()+geom_area(aes(YEAR_WW,AverageofCars,group = 1,colour = 'Average of cars'),car_crashes,fill = "dodgerblue1",alpha = 0.4)+
  geom_line(aes(YEAR_WW,averageofcars,group = 1,linetype ='num of crashes'),car_crashes,fill = "dodgerblue3",colour = "dodgerblue3",size = 1.6) +
  geom_line(aes(car_crashes$YEAR_WW,constantline,group = 1, size = 'constant line' ),car_crashes1,fill = "green4",colour = "green4")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=70, vjust=0.6, face = 'bold'))+
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.2, face = 'bold'))+
  scale_colour_manual('', values = "dodgerblue1")+
  scale_size_manual('',values = 1.4)+
  scale_linetype_manual('',values = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 0)) 
carcrashes_figure
```

Comment: Probably your best bet is to use a separate y-axis for the `average of cars` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreed the idea, using a separate y-axis by @Jim Quirk. As far as I know, ggplot2 isn't very good at doing it, so I used basic plot.

```
# making example ts_data
set.seed(1); data <- matrix(c(rnorm(21, 1000, 100), rnorm(21, 53, 10), rep(53, 21)), ncol=3)
ts_data <- ts(data, start = 1980, frequency = 1)

par(mar=c(4, 4.2, 1.5, 4.2))              # enlarge a right margin
# plot(ts_data[,1])                       # check y-range
plot(ts_data[,2:3], plot.type = "single", ylab="num of crashes & constant line", 
     col=c(2,3), ylim=c(35,100), lwd=2)   # draw "num of crashes" and "constant line"
par(usr = c(par("usr")[1:2], 490, 1310))  # set the second y coordinates
axis(4)                                   # write it on the right side
polygon(x = c(1980:2000, rev(1980:2000)), y = c(ts_data[,1], rep(0,21)), 
        col="#0000FF20", border = "blue") # paint "Average of cars"
mtext(side=4, "Average of cars", line=2.5)
legend("topright",paste(c("num of crashes","constant line","Average of cars")),
   pt.cex=c(0,0,3), lty=c(1,1,0), pch=15, cex=0.9, col=c(2, 3, "#0000FF20"), bty="n", 
   inset=c(0.02,-0.02), y.intersp=1.5)
```

[image]